# Infinite sequence with last

Tags: list, haskell

I want to realize a sequence where `x_n` depends only on `x_{n-1}` as an infinite list.

```
next x_k = x_k +1 --get next element

seq1 n = n : seq1 (next n)

seq2 = 0:[next (last seq2)]
```

`seq1` works, `seq2` does not.
What exactly happens in `seq1`?
Is it because `last` waits forever?
If so, how can I see that e.g. `last` is not good for infinite lists?

Comment: well you already know that your sequence will be *infinite* - so what will `last` be? - `seq1` should be obvious - the only *magic* here is the fact that the list constructor is of course lazy so `seq1 (next n)` will be evaluated on demand

Comment: by the way you can use `unfoldr` in situations like this: ` let mySeq = unfoldr (\b -> Just (b, next b)) 0`

Comment: @CarstenKönig You should post that as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `seq1`

the only magic here is the fact that the list constructor is of course lazy so `seq1 (next n)` will be evaluated on demand and you cannot get into trouble

### `seq2`

As you already saw that your sequence will be infinite it makes no sense to ask for *the last element* of it (using `last`) - so of course this will enter an infinite loop (while trying to find said last element of an infinite list)

If you want to know the details look at what happens when you want the second element of `seq2`

---

remember `last` is defined like this:

```
last [x]                =  x
last (_:xs)             =  last xs
```

---

```
next (last seq2)
= last seq2 + 1
= last (0:[next (last seq2)]) + 1
{ as `seq2` = 0:_ only the second case in `last` applies }
= last [next (last seq2)] + 1
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{ now you are basically back at the first step and you enter an infinite loop }
```

### using `unfoldr`

you can use [`unfoldr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr) to define this rather easily:

```
seq3 = unfoldr (\b -> Just (b, next b)) 0
```

### using `iterate`

as @ReinHeinrichs commented you can also just do

```
seq3 = iterate next 0
```

using [`iterate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate)

indeed `iterate` is actually implemented just like `seq1`:

```
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
iterate f x =  x : iterate f (f x)
```

Comment: Isn't this just `iterate next`?

Comment: @ReinHenrichs yes it is - but I always forget this one :( ... I'll add it (or leave it for you to add another answer)

Comment: Feel free to add it. :)